# Change selected object with multiple nsarraycontrollers

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, binding, nsarraycontroller

I am trying to implement example as shown on [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/WhatAreBindings.html)
Everything works but selectedWeapon does not change.

Q1: I have no idea what I forgot so the selection would work correctly
Q2: According to Apple "the example requires no actual code to set up the user interface". I am filling objects from code. Is there any way to add objects into arrayController in XIB?

```
@implementation Combatant

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)aName
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _weapons = @[@"Dagger", @"Sword", @"Pike"];
    _name = aName;
    _selectedWeapon = [_weapons firstObject];
  }
  return self;
}

@end

@interface Combatant : NSObject


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property id selectedWeapon;
@property NSArray *weapons;

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)aName;

@end
```

Repository: https://github.com/xhruso00/moderatelyComplexBindings

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Q1: The selection index of NSPopupButton wasn't linked to arrayController. Without it the arrayController did not know which option is selected.
Q2: Impossible. Apple talks about the glue code.

[image]